# How can I create a drop-down menu with bootstrap where the options direct users to upload a file?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Load Data
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" id="file1">File</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="file2">File2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

How can I make it so when the user selects one of the option, a file upload window opens (normally created with the following HTML code)

```
<input type="file" name="objfile" id="objfile" >
```

Comment: I suggest making a file upload window (with the `display` attribute set to `none`), and when the user clicks the link, a JS script gets executed which sets the `display` to `block`. Just to add, that's how I'd approach this situation using pure HTML, no bootstrap. I think you can implement this easily in bootstrap though, without changing the responsiveness of your site.